# I keep getting a warning about passing argument makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, function, pointers, printf

C:\Users\OWNER\Downloads\program1.c|61|warning: passing argument 1 of 'get_range' makes pointer from integer without a cast|

Huge problem would really appreciate help professor refuses to help.
I have been staring at this problem for about 3 hours after taking a break for dinner. I still can't figure it out. If you can help explain this to me so I can learn what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*                                                                    */
/* Program Name: program1                                             */
/* Author:       Tommy Lokey                                          */
/* Course:       CS 227, Data Structures and Algorithms               */
/* Date Written: September 2, 2018                                    */
/*                                                                    */
/**********************************************************************/

/**********************************************************************/
/*                                                                    */
/* I pledge  all of the lines  in this C program  are my own original */
/* work and that none of the lines in this C program have been copied */
/* from anyone else, unless I was specifically authorized to do so by */
/*                        my CS227 instructor.                        */
/*                                                                    */
/*                                                                    */
/*                      Signed: _____________________________________ */
/*                                           (signature)              */
/*                                                                    */
/*                                                                    */
/**********************************************************************/

/**********************************************************************/
/*                                                                    */
/* This program asks the user for two wholes numbers, it then sums    */
/* the range of the two whole numbers. It then displays the sum.      */
/*                                                                    */
/**********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf                                   */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                         Symbolic Constants                         */
/**********************************************************************/
#define COURSE_NUMBER  "CS227"    /* PCC assigned course number       */
#define PROGRAM_NUMBER 1          /* Teacher assigned program number  */
#define USER_NAME      "Lokey" /* The Programmer's username        */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                        Function Prototypes                         */
/**********************************************************************/

void print_heading();
/* Print the program heading*/
void get_range(int *p_low_number, int *p_high_number);
int sum_range(int low_number, int high_number);

/**********************************************************************/
/*                         Main Function                              */
/**********************************************************************/
int main()
{
    int low_number,  /* Minimum number entered by user                 */
        high_number; /* Maximum number entered by user                 */

     /* Print the program heading                                       */
     printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
     print_heading();
     get_range(low_number, high_number);
     printf("\nThe sum of all you numbers between %d and", low_number);
     printf("%d (inclusively) is %d", high_number,
      sum_range(low_number, high_number));
     printf("\nThanks for your range summing. Have a nice day! ;-)");
     return 0;
    }


   /**********************************************************************/
   /*                   Print the program heading                        */
   /**********************************************************************/
   void print_heading()
   {
   printf("\n========================================================");
   printf("\n                Program Number: %d",     PROGRAM_NUMBER);
   printf("\n                Programmer: %s",         USER_NAME);
   printf("\n                PCC Course Number: %s",  COURSE_NUMBER);
   printf("\n========================================================");
   printf("\nI'll sum whole numbers in a number range (inclusively)");
   printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------");
   return;
   }

    /**********************************************************************/    
    /*                        Get Range Function                          */
    /**********************************************************************/
    void get_range(int *p_low_number, int *p_high_number)
    {
     printf("\nEnter a range of whole numbers now, lower number first:");
     printf("\n  What is your small number: ");
     scanf(" %d", p_low_number);
     printf("\n  Give your large number: ");
     scanf(" %d", p_high_number);
     return;
    }

    /**********************************************************************/
    /*                        Sum Range Function                          */
    /**********************************************************************/
    int sum_range(int low_number, int high_number)
    {
      int range_counter = 0;

      for(low_number; low_number <= high_number; low_number++)
    {
      range_counter = range_counter + low_number;
    }
    return range_counter;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_range(low_number, high_number);` => `get_range(&low_number, &high_number);`

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_range()` expects two pointers. That's because it will use these pointers to assign values to variables from another function.

Your professor expects you to use this function to read into two variables that are declared in you `main()`, apparently. So you have to take the **addresses** of theses variables and pass them to `get_range()`, not their values.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a wrong argument mate! You are accepting `integer pointers` in your `get_range` declaration, but passing values in the function call.

In your case, the type conversion is from `integer` to `integer` pointer. In some cases, the function takes void pointers to accommodate for all the data-types.
In such cases, you would need to typecast the arguments as `(void *)`

This would be the function declaration in most well written modular functions:

```
int CheckIfIn(char ch, void *checkstring);
```

You would need to pass the argument as a void pointer, provided the Vowels is not a char pointer

```
 if(CheckIfIn(letter, (void *)Vowels) ){
        printf("this is a vowel.\n");
    }
```